# How to add a color scheme to PyCharm?

Tags: windows-7, python, pycharm

I downloaded the IDLE-like color scheme from [here](https://github.com/d1ffuz0r/pycharm-themes/blob/master/colors/IDLE.icls). However, I can't find where to install this for use with **PyCharm** on Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of tweaking with file path.
1) Download a color theme from [here](http://www.ideacolorthemes.org/home/)
2) Pycharm > File > Import Setting > point to the color theme downloaded in (1)

Pycharm should recognise this as a theme (i.e. only the theme checkbox is available) in the import dialog that follows (2)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I tried placing it in the wrong place. According to [this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/project-and-ide-settings.html), The file should be installed in `<User home>\.PyCharmXX\config\colors`. Then, restarting the IDE enables the selection of the scheme from the Settings pane.